# Let xgettext find keywords in comments

Tags: php, command-line, poedit, xgettext

As default, *xgettext* ignores any keyword found within a comment block.

```
<?php // file.php
echo _('This text will be found');
//_('This text will be ignored');
```

Is it possible to override this behaviour? I've tried by adding `//_` as a keyword, but this fails as well. It seems comments have priority over keywords:

`xgettext -o output.po --language=PHP -k_ -k//_ file.php`

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, that xgettext filters out comments and i do not know of a way to avoid this. However, as an alternative solution you could just use *sed* to replace comments before feeding the file to xgettext:

```
sed 's/\/\/_/_/g' file.php | xgettext -o output.po --language=PHP -
```

Comment: Aah, that is a nice creative solution! Thanks for the idea and help!

Comment: I don't know if this is possible with only poedit. I am using poedit only as editor not for generating .po files, because in my case i have some additional datasources (database) i feed into the .po files. I've had a quick look at the preferences of poedit, but it doesn't seem to have any possibilities to configure such things ...